# Find the $Θ$ of $∑\log\log k$?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, recursion, computability

I am struggling finding the $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log \log k$$

I know that $∑_{k=1}^n \log k = \log(n!) \implies Θ(n\log(n))$.

But unfortunately that does me help me to find the $Θ$ for $∑_{k=1}^n \log \log k$.

I can do not get a faculty to estimate the lower and upper bound . I think I have to use the rules of calculation of the log. So instead of having two sums, having one sum and one product, but that does really bring me closer to find an estimation of the upper or lower bound for the sum.

Edit: Thank you for the comments

$\log \log k$ with $k=1$ is undefined.
Wolfram alpha says $ \log \log k $ at $k = 1 = -∞$.  In the question it's asked from $k = 1$ to $n$

If it is undefined, there is no Θ I guess?

If it is -∞, I guess there is no Θ neither, since you can not really bound it?

And does anyone know the solution if the sum starts at $k=2$?

Comment: Your question was rather sloppily worded. I edited to clean this up. You would get more help if you put a bit more thought into your asking.

Comment: $\log \log k$ at $k=1$ is undefined, no? Is there a convention I am missing here or should the sum start at $k=2$?

Comment: @mike thank you very much for cleaning it up!

Comment: True log(1) = 0 and log(0) = not defined. Wolfram alpha says log log k at k = 1 = -∞. In the question it's asked from k = 1 to n. And there are no other conventions. Maybe it's a mistake of the question maker, but it is asked like that

Comment: So I guess then there is no Θ of it? or how would it be answered if it's -∞? Guess you can not say it then since you can not find a lower bound, just  -∞

Comment: My intuition is that $\sum_{k=2}^n\log\log k \in \Theta(n)$, but I am not sure how to prove that.

Comment: @NapD.Lover I was the one who edited it and put in the subscripts. Yes you are correct, $k$ should be 2,3,4,.... instead of 1,2,3,4,... My oversight...

Comment: In any event $\log \log 1$ is $-\infty$ so for any finite $n$ the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \log \log k$ is $-\infty$; whereas $\sum_{k=2}^n \log \log k$ is $\theta(n \log  \log n)$ as per the answers below. If I had to guess I would say the authors meant $k$ to start from at least 2, but it is quite reasonable that one should be able to answer for $k$ starting from 1.

Comment: I messaged the author and it turned out that it was a mistake. The sum should start with $k = 2$. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if $f(n)$ is positive, monotonic increasing,
and unbounded,
and defined for $n \ge n_0$,
if $f(n)$ increases slowly enough,
then
$\sum_{n_0 \le k \le n} f(k)
=\Theta(nf(n))
$.

This is off the 
top of my head,
but I think a sufficient slow growth condition would be
$\lim\sup_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f(an)}{f(n)}
\le 1$
for some $a > 1$.

For $f(n) = \log(n)$
or
$f(n) = \log\log(n)$
or more iteratedly 
(wasn't a word, is now)
logs,
$a = 2$
works.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

$$n \log \log n \geq \sum_{k=2}^n \log \log k \geq \sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}}^n \log \log k  \geq \frac{n}{2} \log \log \frac{n}{2}$$
The rightmost step is taking the minimal term and multiplying it by the number of terms. Note that

$$\log \log \frac{n}{2} = \log(\log n - \log 2) = \Theta(\log \log n)$$
And so we get the sum is $\Theta(n \log \log n)$. I'll let you fill in the formal details regarding the $\frac{n}{2}$, and proving the former bound.

Comment: Thank you very much!